# Android numberpicker set value seen on open

Tags: android, numberpicker

I am looking to set the numberpicker a default value when I click on it. Now it shows "0". I want to pick the number you see as first in the numberpicker. 
I am working with integers.

It should be very easy, but I can't find it. This needs to be done programmatically.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should call [setValue()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html#setValue(int)) on the NumberPicker instance, if you wish to use a default value:

```
numberPicker.setValue(5); // example value
```

Comment: I'm so stupid. I used the setvalue but for a unknown reason it didn't work then. So that's why I asked this question. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Manu nope, just faced the same problem when I called `setValue` first, and then called `setMin/setMax`. When calling `setValue` after `setMin/Max` it works.

Answer (score 17):

Be careful, in kotlin you have to put `setValue()` after `setMinValue()` and `setMaxValue()`

This works:

```
numberPicker.minValue=0
numberPicker.maxValue=30
numberPicker.value=15
```

This doesn't work:

```
numberPicker.value=15
numberPicker.minValue=0
numberPicker.maxValue=30
```

Comment: Thanks man, saved my ass. What kinda stupid bug is that, Jeez!

Comment: What does this have to do with Kotlin? It's calling into the extact same code.

Comment: Google/Android is replaced Java by Kotlin, two languages are similar

Comment: this should be fixed. supposedly unrelated code should not affect one another.

Comment: Such a nonsense bug. Present still now.

Comment: thank you so much for making this explicit! Was stuck with this for ages

Comment: In java as well....

Answer (score 0):

There is a [setValue() method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html#setValue(int)) in the `NumberPicker` to set the value